# How to put a marker or bubble on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am new to iOS and I have an UIImageView which I want to put a marker or bubble when user tapped on the image. Any way to put a marker or bubble on UIImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just create a new view (can be UIView or another UIImageView) and add it as a subview of that image view.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a tap gesture to your `imageView` and when you tap on it add a bubble image inside it on the desired place.

**So something like this:**

1. Create a `UIImageView`
2. Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it
3. In the function for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` add a new `UIImageView` inside the first one

**Code example:**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
imageVIew.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
imageVIew.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

func imageTapped() {
    let buble = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    buble.image = UIImage(named: "buble")
    imageVIew.addSubview(buble)
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Sample project that you can continue working with:**

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rqn5536m1358wn/TapOnImageView.zip?dl=0&m=) is a sample project that you can try with that does what I have described above.

Comment: Can You please tell me after putting bubble image i want to save as pdf with bubble image is it possible?

Comment: @VishalParmar, checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710554/swift-uiimage-convert-as-pdf) it might help you.